Unity add facebook login with ads
I'm integrating Facebook login into a Unity app. However, there's an issue because I'm also running ads for my app on the Facebook platform at the same time. I’ve attached an AppID specifically for running ads, which listens and sends event tracking data to Facebook Ads.
But now I need to integrate Facebook login into my app, which requires me to add a second AppID for Facebook authentication.
I’m wondering if there's a way to use two AppIDs simultaneously—authenticate users with one app and send event tracking to the other? Or have I misunderstood something along the way? Please help me.
